# automatic setting of development team on Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode10

When I'm downloading sample project and open on Xcode, everytime I got this error that I need to set the development team (replace with the original development team that create the project)

The year is 2018.
Xcode version is 10.

Am I missing something, and there is setting that I can switch ON\YES\Do It
and then Xcode will AUTOMATIC will set my development team, my 1 and only development team ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything. The development team is already set in the project you downloaded, and that is the development team you are shown when you open the project.